# Style Span and Jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

Hopefully a simple question that I'm having that blank moment over. I'm trying to style a Span tag in my HTML (which ties to a block of jquery).

My SHOW span is holding the background I set but not the width. While the HIDE centers, and has the appropriate width. Not sure as to why. What am I missing that is preventing the first Span with "SHOW" to style completely?  Fiddle below.

```
.slider{
display:none;
}
.collapseSlider{
display:none;
}
.sliderExpanded .collapseSlider{
display:block;
width: 100%;
text-align: center;
}
.sliderExpanded .expandSlider{
  display:none;
}
.dark {background:#0082d1; text-align: center; width: 100%;}
.light {background:#003a6f; text-align: center; width: 100%;}  

<p class="toggler" id="toggler-slideOne">
<span class="expandSlider dark">SHOW</span><span class="collapseSlider dark">HIDE</span>
 </p>
  <div class="slider" id="slideOne">
 <p>Slide One lorem ipsum opsum...</p>
 <span class="closeSlider">Close</span>
 </div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/f8xxk/

As always thanks for your time and continued support!

Comment: Like this http://jsfiddle.net/f8xxk/1/?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `span` is an inline element (they ignore the width property) you would need to set a floating to that span or set the display to `inline-block` in order to let this span have a `width`

```
.dark {background:#0082d1; text-align: center; width: 100%;}
span {display:inline-block  }
/*Any of this will make the span to have a block and don't ignore the width property*/
span {display:block}
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/f8xxk/4/)

Comment: Of course! Simple yet easily overlooked. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

You can't set the width on an inline element, setting it's display property to block would be one way of fixing it.

Modified fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/f8xxk/3/

```
span {
    display: block;
}
```